# Выполнение с задержкой (setInterval, интервал)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы функция каждый раз выполнялась с задержкой `500мс` пока `(frameWidth / 2) != enemyDistance`, после функция закрывается.

```
var motionEnemy = function () {
    if (rightSid === true) {
         while ( (frameWidth / 2) != enemyDistance ) {
             console.log('step');
             enemy.css({marginRight: enemyDistance + 'px'});
             enemyDistance += STEP_LENGHT;
             setTimeout(motionEnemy,__self.GAME_TICK*);
         }
    };
setTimeout(motionEnemy(),__self.GAME_TICK);
```

Comment: `while` заменить на `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно написал @Max Timakov, `while` в данном случае не нужно, потому что <s>есть рекурсия</s> переменная motionEnemy, содержит в себе функцию, которая при выполнении условия, ещё раз вызывает обращается к этой переменной, поэтому достаточно `if`, чтобы проверять условие в каждом обращении к переменной.

**UPD** Исправил описательную часть и перенёс `i++;` выше по заявкам телезрителей.

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 10;

var motionEnemy = function() {
  if (j >= i) {
    console.log('step' + i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(motionEnemy, '500');
  }
};
setTimeout(motionEnemy, '1500');
```

Comment: рекурсии здесь нет—`motionEnemy()` не вызывает себя (ни прямо ни опосредовано: `i++` выполняется *до* следущего вызова), а делегирует вызов javascript движку (stackoverflow не получится сделать).

Comment: а если я напишу `function motionEnemy() {}` вместо `var motionEnemy = function() {}`, это будет являться рекурсией?

Comment: Нет, это не меняет, то как `setTimeout()` работает.

Comment: @jfs, хм, странно, на хабре и тут я встретил примеры, где именно такой вызов через `setTimeout()`  называют косвенной рекурсией, исправил ответ, так правильно?

Comment: @jfs, и это не является рекурсией? `function motionEnemy() { setTimeout(function(){
       motionEnemy();
   }, '500'); };`

Comment: нет. Даже, `function f() { setTimeout(f, 0); }` не является рекурсией. Рекурсия: `function f() { f(); }`. Представьте у вас вместо `setTimeout()` написано (не настоящая реализация): `queue.push({function: motionEnemy, args: [], deadline: current_time + 500})` и после того как контроль переходит к движку: он  и вызывает подходящие функции из очереди `queue`, у которых `deadline` прошла. [Посмотрите на картинки](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=771)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за инфу, а то с теорией у меня слабовато, особенно в таких тонких моментах :)